# data-mage-init not working on CMS page

Tags: magento2, javascript

If I add this to a CMS page then it pull in the javascript to the page correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function (jQuery, jQueryBootstrap) {

    });
</script>
```

But if I try it with data attribute like so:

```
<div data-mage-init='{"bootstrap": {}}'>

</div>
```

Then the javascript is not pulled into the page.

Do data attributes only work in phtml files?  Docs seem to say I can use either.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of quotation marks around the configuration part of the init config may be causing a JSON parse error (visible in developer tools javascript console).

```
<div data-mage-init='{"bootstrap": "{}"}'>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100142)

Comment: This solves the problem often for me. I regard the lack of quotation marks as a syntax error and I believe Magento does too.

Comment: Then I was mislead by your wording. The answer sounded like a question. It would help if you add the information from the comment to the answer.

Comment: In the JSON syntax this two statements (`{}` and `"{}"`) are different, and both are valid.

Comment: this did fix an "tag gets eaten up and chewed up broken on save" issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference between both code pieces.

### First one: an inline script with RequireJS call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function (jQuery, jQueryBootstrap) {

    });
</script>
```

- RequireJs will load files `jquery.js`, `bootstrap.js` in an async way
- When both are loaded (no matter will page loaded or no) and both are *executed*, then the callback will be executed. In the arguments, it will receive *something* that `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js`modules return.
- If `bootstrap.js` depends on `jQuery` but doesn't contain an explicit dependency on `'jquery'` module it randomly fails.

### Second one: mage-init initializing

```
<div data-mage-init='{"bootstrap": {}}'>

</div>
```

- Magento's JS app will wait for page onload event
- After page onload, Magento's JS app will collect `data-mage-init` attributes
- Magento's JS app with RequireJS will load `bootstrap.js` and executes it
- <strike>If `bootstrap.js` depends on `jQuery` but doesn't contain explicit dependency on `'jquery'` module it fails.</strike> Actually no. Magento's JS app depends on jQuery itself. So jQuery will be load anyway before `bootstrap.js` executes. So it is a type of lucky.
- Magento's JS app will try to execute *something*, that `bootstrap.js` returns. This callback will receive parsed object from `mage-init` JSON as *`config`*, and reference on DOM node `<div data-mage-init..>` as *`element`*.